# Convert InputStream to StringBuilder and StringBuilder to OutputStream

Tags: java, concurrency, inputstream, stringbuilder, outputstream

I have a specific use-case where i need to be able to convert data i recieve on an:

- InputStream and store in a StringBuilder
- StringBuilder and write to an OutputStream

I dont want to convert to and from Strings since i'll already have the StringBuilder (but if it's the same as having a String with the full contents in memory either way, then i can just change them to string).
What i dont understand is when I created the different transfer types between them in the classes below to test, i somehow deadlock even though i've made each of the transfer classes be separate threads (as `Callable<void>`) so i'm confused why it's happening and i even tried replacing with Runnbale/Thread and doing `start()`, `join()` with still the same problem; I guess it's some coding logic mistake that i can't seem to see.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class Test {
    
    private static String create() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
            sb.append(i+".123401234").append(System.lineSeparator());
        return sb.toString();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        ByteArrayInputStream initial_in = new ByteArrayInputStream(create().getBytes());    // data
        PipedInputStream in = new PipedInputStream();                               // intermediary pipe
        PipedOutputStream out = new PipedOutputStream(in);                          // connect OutputStream to pipe InputStream 
        StringBuilder final_out = new StringBuilder();
        NativeToNativeTransfer ntnt = new NativeToNativeTransfer(initial_in, out); // InputStream to OutputStream
        NativeToCustomTransfer ntct = new NativeToCustomTransfer(in, final_out);   // InputStream to StringBuilder 
        Future<Void> f1 = executor.submit(ntnt);
        Future<Void> f2 = executor.submit(ntct);
        f1.get(); f2.get();     // deadlock here ? 
        System.out.println(final_out);
        System.out.println("Done");
    }

    public static class StreamTransfer implements Callable<Void> {
        public static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
        private InputStream in;
        private OutputStream out;
        
        public StreamTransfer(InputStream in, OutputStream out) {
            this.in = in;
            this.out = out;
        }
        
        @Override
        public Void call() throws Exception {
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(in);
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(out);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            while (bis.read(buffer) != -1) 
                bos.write(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
            bos.flush();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static class NativeToCustomTransfer implements Callable<Void> {
        private InputStream in;
        private StringBuilder sb;
        
        public NativeToCustomTransfer(InputStream in, StringBuilder out) {
            this.in = in;
            sb = out;
        }
        
        @Override
        public Void call() throws Exception {
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(in);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[StreamTransfer.BUFFER_SIZE];
            while (bis.read(buffer) != -1) 
                sb.append(new String(buffer));
            return null;
        }
    }
    
    public static class CustomToNativeTransfer extends StreamTransfer { 
        public CustomToNativeTransfer(StringBuilder in, OutputStream out) {
            super(new ByteArrayInputStream(in.toString().getBytes()), out);
        }
    }
    
    public static class NativeToNativeTransfer extends StreamTransfer {
        public NativeToNativeTransfer(InputStream in, OutputStream out) {
            super(in, out);
        }
    }
    
    public static class CustomToCustomTransfer {
        public CustomToCustomTransfer(StringBuilder in, StringBuilder out) {
            in.chars().forEach(out::append);
        } 
    }
}
```

## Edit:

After fixing all the mistakes pointed out by DuncG and Holger, the code actually works as planned and doesn't deadlock anymore:

```
package test;

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class Test {
    
    private static String create() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
            sb.append(i+".123401234").append(System.lineSeparator());
        return sb.toString();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        ByteArrayInputStream initial_in = new ByteArrayInputStream(create().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));  // data
        PipedInputStream in = new PipedInputStream();                               // intermediary pipe
        PipedOutputStream out = new PipedOutputStream(in);                          // connect OutputStream to pipe InputStream 
        StringBuilder final_out = new StringBuilder();
        NativeToNativeTransfer ntnt = new NativeToNativeTransfer(initial_in, out); // InputStream to OutputStream
        NativeToCustomTransfer ntct = new NativeToCustomTransfer(in, final_out);   // InputStream to StringBuilder 
        Future<Void> f1 = executor.submit(ntnt);
        Future<Void> f2 = executor.submit(ntct);
        f1.get(); f2.get();     // no more deadlock
        System.out.println(final_out);
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
    
    public static class NativeToCustomTransfer implements Callable<Void> {
        private InputStream in;
        private StringBuilder sb;
        
        public NativeToCustomTransfer(InputStream in, StringBuilder out) {
            this.in = in;
            sb = out;
        }
        
        @Override
        public Void call() throws Exception {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[StreamTransfer.BUFFER_SIZE];
            int read = 0;
            while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) 
                sb.append(new String(buffer, 0, read, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            in.close();
            return null;
        }
    }
    
    public static class CustomToNativeTransfer extends StreamTransfer { 
        public CustomToNativeTransfer(StringBuilder in, OutputStream out) {
            super(new ByteArrayInputStream(in.toString().getBytes()), out);
        }
    }
    
    public static class NativeToNativeTransfer extends StreamTransfer {
        public NativeToNativeTransfer(InputStream in, OutputStream out) {
            super(in, out);
        }
    }
    
    public static class CustomToCustomTransfer {
        public CustomToCustomTransfer(StringBuilder in, StringBuilder out) {
            in.chars().forEach(out::append);
        } 
    }
    
    public static class StreamTransfer implements Callable<Void> {
        public static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
        private InputStream in;
        private OutputStream out;
        
        public StreamTransfer(InputStream in, OutputStream out) {
            this.in = in;
            this.out = out;
        }
        
        @Override
        public Void call() throws Exception {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            int read = 0;
            while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) 
                out.write(buffer, 0, read);
            in.close();
            out.close();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what you are trying to accomplish is to read from one InputStream and write to an OutputStream using a StringBuilder as the intermediary?

Comment: Yeah that's exactly it, i want to be able to use a way to transfer data from streams and string builders interchangeably

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) None of your streams are closed when done, that means the reads from pipe will be waiting for more input. Change flush to close. For cleaner code use try with resources to guarantee that each call() closes the in/out streams. In later JRE (9+ maybe?) you only need to reference a variable in try-with-resources block to make it autoclose:

```
try(var try_will_autoclose_this_resource = out)
{
    while ((len = in.read(buffer)) != -1)
        out.write(buffer, 0, len);
}
```

2) your logic for in.read(buff) should store value into local variable so it copies the right length

```
while ( (len = bis.read(buffer)) != -1) bos.write(buffer, 0, len);
```

3) You use new byte[BUFFER_SIZE] so I/O is done in chunks, this means all your BufferedInput.Output streams are unnecessary

4) Using new String(buffer) may not work if your default character set is multi-byte, as it could incomplete set of bytes for final character.

Comment: Also, `new String(buffer)` bears the same error as mentioned in point 2. It should use the number of bytes actually read, instead of the whole buffer.

Comment: For 1, i wanted to have control over when i closed the streams but i guess it makes sense, for point 2,  i had initially done that, but somehow i thought it's useless so i'll try to fix all read/write + String(buffer) to store the number of data to write.
For point 3, I'm glad you explained this i was always confused, so that means Everywhere i used a BufferedInput/Output stream is useless since i'm already using a buffer ? And so i technically i made double bufferring instead of getting a performance boost from that ? =v Thanks for explaining my mistakes

Comment: @DuncG After i fixed all the points you pointed out it works exactly as expected!,Thanks a lot! the only thing i'd want a confirmation for is the 3rd point and if i was actually stupidly double-buffering, and if that's the case then i don't see the uses of those buffering classes anymore if the only way we read and write to streams is through buffers =v unless i should read byte per byte if i want the Buffered classes to use buffering behind the scenes ?

Comment: And last question for point #1, I would like to use a try-with-resources block but since my StreamTransfer class gets the streams as attributes there's no way for me to use it in that case right ?

Comment: Hi @Lorenzo For 3: View the code for BufferedIn/OutputStream, they allocate a byte[] (8192). Both make the byte-at-time calls read/write(byte) work on the internal byte[], and each handle use of calling read/write(byte[]) on the underlying stream. So they wouldn't help you much as you already call the more effective read/write(byte[]) calls. BIS/BOS speed up byte-at-time read/write operations dramatically if the underlying stream is slow such as a HDD, website or network access. In your case though either type of read/write will be quick enough as all your data is in memory.

Comment: @Lorenzo. For 1, I'll update my answer,Adding a variable inside the try block makes it autoclose on exit the block